# Restrict access to certain tables for users who have DBA roles?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, role, dml

I have an Oracle Database which includes many users and some of them have DBA roles. The thing is, DBA's shouldn't delete any records from  SYS.AUD$ table. Is there a way that i can achieve this?

Comment: Simple answer: revoke the DBA role from these users.

Comment: Thanks but i need an alternative. Can i exclude  from accessing specific schema? DBA roles shouldn't manipulate data in SYS directly.

Comment: in Oracle 11g you cannot stop someone with full DBA privileges from manipulating the audit trail. You can *audit the audit trail itself* so you'll know if anyone has been naughty, or send audit records to file system files so that a database user can't delete them directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have an Oracle Database which includes many users and some of them have DBA roles.

Are they DBAs?
DBAs *know better* than to "muck about" with the Audit Trail.
If they're not DBAs, then they should not have this Role.
Period.

Always keep the biggest and best tools for yourself - so that you can clean up the mess that other people / processes make!

I would suggest immediately starting work on finding *another* way of providing what these Users [think they] want.